# Socket.Io pushing multiple sockets into a room

Tags: socket.io

I need to be able to push several 'sockets' into a room at the same time when it gets created

Socket.io receives a list of userids

The correct socket id gets found via 'var s = c_user_socket[d];'
Where d is the user_id and c_user_sockets holds the user_id-socket_id relation

If a match is found the variable 's' becomes something like this

'/#-TVfzhM9oGLtmiPdAAAC

To join the room I do : s.join("conversation_" + chat_id);

Socket.io then exits with the error

Missing error handler on `socket`.

```
TypeError: s.join is not a function
at /var/www/html/controller/servers/socket_io_server.js:29:7
at Array.forEach (native)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/controller/servers/socket_io_server.js:24:16)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
at Socket.onevent (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:335:8)
at Socket.onpacket (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:295:12)
at Client.ondecoded (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
at Decoder.add (/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
```

How can I push multiple sockets into a room at once?

Sockets are found via arrays :

```
socket.on('identify', function(data) {
    data = String(data);
    c_socket_user[socket.id] = data;
    c_user_socket[data] = socket.id;
})
```

Comment: What is c_user_socket

Comment: c_user_sockets holds the user_id-socket_id relation